# How do I set the domain for a Twisted Session cookie

Tags: python, twisted, session-cookies

I have a Twisted web application using Twisted's HTTP sessions.

How can I specify the domain of the session's cookie?

For example: my application is running on `sub.example.com`, but I want to set the cookie's domain to `.example.com`.